# Why are these objects not equal by default in D?

Tags: object, hash, d, equals

Take a look at this simple class I'm building as the base to store the results of string matching algorithms:

```
/** Match of a single pattern in full to a single text. */
class Match {
    uint Tpos;

    this(in uint Tpos) { this.Tpos = Tpos; }

    override string toString() {
        return text("Match: Text@",Tpos);
    }
}
```

Here's where things get weird:

```
auto m1 = new Match(1), m2 = new Match(1);
writeln(m1.toHash());
writeln(m2.toHash());
writeln(m1 == m2);
```

prints

```
4464528
4464512
false
```

I see no reason why these two objects should not be considered equal by default.  I suppose I could write a custom `toHash()` and `opEquals()` function, but that seems like overkill.  According to Andrei Alexandrescu's [book](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/tdpl/) on the D programming language (great book!), "By default, the hash is computed by using the bitwise representation of the object."  Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the source code (dmd2/src/druntime/src/object_.d):

```
class Object
{
/* snip */
    /**
     * Compute hash function for Object.
     */
    hash_t toHash() @trusted nothrow
    {   
        // BUG: this prevents a compacting GC from working, needs to be fixed
        return cast(hash_t)cast(void*)this;
    }
/* snip */
    /**
     * Returns !=0 if this object does have the same contents as obj.
     */
    equals_t opEquals(Object o)
    {
        return this is o;
    }
}
```

So the answer is simply that's the way the code is written - they do an identity check rather than a content check. Why is it this way? I don't really know, but my guess is it was simple to write originally and works well enough that nobody has bothered to come back to it and change it.

On the newsgroup, there's been some discussion of removing these functions from Object entirely, so if you want == on your classes, you'll have to implement something. But the time it takes for newsgroup talk to become action when it comes to things like this is usually pretty long. And they might change their minds.

The best way of using class equality currently and probably in the foreseeable future is to write your own opEquals method in the class.

Comment: Thanks for the source code and insight.  I didn't realize == compared by identity by default.  I ended up rewriting it as a struct anyway as I will want to copy the object by value most of the time.

Answer (score 8):

You have to implement `toHash` on your own, since `Object.toHash` depends on the address. If I remember correctly it's just a `return cast(hash_t)cast(void*)this`.

**EDIT:** Yes, I remember correctly: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/object_.d#L88

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple: By default, `opEquals` for objects compares the objects' addresses. You *must* override it if you want value semantics (or just use a `struct`).

Side note: Your use of `in` is incorrect. `in` is short for `scope const` where `scope` means "I won't escape this parameter outside my stack frame" (which you do by assigning it to a class field). Unfortunately the compiler doesn't enforce this yet, which is why you didn't get an error.

Comment: I don't sure, but I think that scope is about references (or pointers) escaping and that it's legal to copy scoped pure value arguments to outer variables.

Comment: `scope` (and therefore `in`) on function parameters is supposed to prevent references associated with that argument escaping the function at all (which would include assigning it to a member variable) - though it's true that the checks are _not_ correctly implemented right now. However, in this particular case, it's fine regardless, because the parameter is a `uint`, which is a value type. `scope` has no real meaning for value types - only reference types - because the argument is copied and so there's no reference to even escape.

Comment: I suppose `in` is not the best modifier here; `const` is a better option, though with such a short constructor it probably does not matter what qualifiers are used.  Thanks for the info on `scope`.